# Código não apresenta gráficos

Tags: python, gráfico, pycharm

Estou tentando criar um programa que me diga quantas vezes um agente do Valorant foi escolhido em cada mapa, nos campeonatos mais importantes do VCT 2023.

Entretanto, só recebo uma mensagem de texto, sem os gráficos solicitados.

Esse é o código que estou utilizando:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# URL do site do Liquipedia com as informações dos mapas
url = 'https://liquipedia.net/valorant/Main_Page'

# Faz a requisição HTTP para obter o conteúdo da página
response = requests.get(url)

# Cria o objeto BeautifulSoup para fazer o parsing do HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Encontra a tabela com as informações dos mapas
table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

# Encontra todas as linhas da tabela
rows = table.find_all('tr')

# Cria um dicionário vazio para armazenar os dados dos agentes por mapa
agent_data = {}

# Itera pelas linhas da tabela, ignorando a primeira linha que contém os cabeçalhos
for row in rows[1:]:
    # Obtém o nome do mapa na primeira coluna da linha
    map_name = row.find('td').text.strip()

    # Obtém todas as células da segunda coluna da linha (que contém os agentes)
    agent_cells = row.find_all('td')
    if len(agent_cells) > 1:
        agents = agent_cells[1].find_all('a')

        # Cria uma lista vazia para armazenar os nomes dos agentes
        agent_names = []

        # Itera pelos links de cada agente, adicionando o nome de cada agente à lista
        for agent in agents:
            agent_names.append(agent.text.strip())

        # Adiciona os dados dos agentes ao dicionário
        agent_data[map_name] = agent_names

# Cria uma lista com todos os agentes encontrados nos mapas
all_agents = []
for agents in agent_data.values():
    all_agents.extend(agents)

# Cria um dicionário com a contagem de cada agente encontrado
agent_count = {}
for agent in all_agents:
    if agent in agent_count:
        agent_count[agent] += 1
    else:
        agent_count[agent] = 1

# Cria um gráfico de pizza com a contagem de agentes
labels = agent_count.keys()
values = agent_count.values()
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Agentes mais utilizados nos mapas do Valorant')

# Adiciona essa nova linha abaixo
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.raise_()
```

Esse é o resultado:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP4SH.png)

Comment: O problema não é com o matplotlib ou pyplot. A lógica usada na raspagem não é concomitante ao HTML da página. Ao final do laço `for row in rows[1:]:` o dicionário `agent_data` continua vazio.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.